# Reshaping nested struct array to cell array having elements with different sizes

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

In MATLAB, I have a struct array of the following form:

```
a(1).b.c = rand(1,10);
a(1).b.cSize = length(a(1).b.c);
a(2).b.c = rand(1,11);
a(2).b.cSize = length(a(2).b.c);
a(3).b.c = rand(1,12);
a(3).b.cSize = length(a(3).b.c);
a(4).b.c = rand(1,13);
a(4).b.cSize = length(a(4).b.c);
a(5).b.c = rand(1,14);
a(5).b.cSize = length(a(5).b.c);
a(6).b.c = rand(1,15);
a(6).b.cSize = length(a(6).b.c);
```

I would like to create a cell array `c` that contains the differently sized fields `a.b.c` of the nested struct, without using for loops.

I tried the following:

```
c = {a.b.c}
```

which is not working and returns the following error message:

> Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression,
>   but there were 6 results.

The best solution I've found so far is the following

```
cellfun(@(x) x.c, {a.b}, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Is there a faster solution without using `cellfun`? Maybe some `reshape` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a structrue array from `a.b` then extract the field `c` from the array.

```
ab = [a.b];
result = {ab.c}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Could you please have a look at my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571366/reshaping-nested-struct-arrays-to-cell-array-having-elements-with-different-size) with a different  form of the nested structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a one-line version of rahnema1's answer:

```
[result{1:numel(a)}] = subsref([a.b], substruct('.','c'));
```

I strongly discourage you from using this in the wild though, almost no-one understands this on first read (which is a good rule of thumb to use for coding).