# Reshaping nested struct arrays to cell array having elements with different sizes

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, nested, cell-array

I have a similar question to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546956/reshaping-nested-struct-array-to-cell-array-having-elements-with-different-sizes/45547151#45546956). This time the form of the nested structure looks like this:

```
Sizes = [2, 5, 8, 6, 3];
cells = 5;
for i = 1:cells
    for j = 1:Sizes(i)
        a(i).b.c(j).d = rand(1,1);
    end
    a(i).b.Size = Sizes(i);
end
```

Again I would like to put all the `d` values of `a(:).b.c(:)` into a single `cell array` that contains `1 x cells` cells.

Here is my solution using `cellfun` but I would like to avoid this function:

```
ab = [a.b];
abc = {ab.c};
abcd = cellfun(@(x) [x.d], abc, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Using the previous solution for `abc`:

```
abc = [ab.c];
```

creates a `1x24` struct array with field `d`. I thought of using the `Size` field to reshape this result into a `cell array` but I don't know how or if it is possible. Do you have a better appraoch without using loops and without `cellfun`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) as follows:

```
ab = [a.b];
abc = [ab.c];
abcd = mat2cell([abc.d], 1, [ab.Size]);
```